# CMD prompt display issue with raspberry pi 4 core-image-full-cmdline build on HDMI screen

Tags: yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am newbie for raspberry PI 4. I have setup and built core-image-full-cmdline-raspberrypi4-64-20230415042309.rootfs.rpi-sdimg after build, unable to see the results on display. not sure any additional settings required?

My bblayers.conf has:

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
/home/jr/sources/poky/meta \
/home/jr/sources/poky/meta-poky \
/home/jr/sources/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
/home/jr/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
/home/jr/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
/home/jr/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
/home/jr/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
/home/jr/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
/home/jr/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \
/home/jr/sources/meta-raspberrypi \
"
```

My local.conf file has:

```
MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi4-64"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"


EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += " ssh-server-openssh " # For SSH access
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " openssh "

IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tar.xz ext3 rpi-sdimg"
IMAGE_FSTYPES += "wic wic.gz wic.bmap"

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " apt git curl wget htop ntpdate " # Getting these extra commands for installation

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " netdata "
PACKAGECONFIG:append_pn-netdata = " dbengine "

ENABLE_UART = "1"

BB_NUMBER_THREADS = '6'
PARALLEL_MAKE = '-j 6'

USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats"

PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"


BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
HALT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
HALT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
HALT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
HALT,/tmp,10M,1K"

PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"

CONF_VERSION = "2"
```

any settings to be done in config.txt? Tried setting below lines but not working.

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=6
```

am I missing something?